# link to generate random string and feed into text box

Tags: javascript, html, string, random

i have a text box like this

```
<input class="form-textbox validate[required]" type="text" name="newvalue" id="newvalue" value="" size="15" />
```

I would like a link next to this box, when clicked generates a 8 character, alpha-numeric, one upper case character string and feeds into this text box.

currently i have this code to generate 8 character alpha-numeric string but no upper case in this, and i think it only works in php, i need something for html

```
substr(md5(rand(0, 1000000)), 0, 8);
```

What would be the javascript to do the above string generation and insertion when link is clicked in an html page?

Comment: are you trying to create a password? use phps `echo` to print in html

Comment: im trying to create a password and instead of print to html im trying to feed this password into a text box, this text box is for admin page where user profile info like email, password, name, address etc is updated

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to create a random string in JS (thus you don't really need to involve the md5 algorithm) you can adapt [this snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/96yBe/3/):

```
function getRandomString(stringLength)
{
    var ret = "";
    for (var i=0; i<stringLength; i++){
        var randNumb = 58; 
        //Use this cycle to discard values between 57 and 65 (non alpha-num ascii codes)
        while (randNumb> 57 && randNumb < 65) { 
            randNumb = Math.floor(Math.random() * (90 - 48) + 48);
        }
        ret += String.fromCharCode(randNumb);
    }
    return ret;
}

alert(getRandomString(8));
```

If a random alphabetic string is good enough you can remove the randNumb init and the while cycle below, [using only a random number between 65 and 90](http://jsfiddle.net/uKxxd/).

Comment: That would work, how can i feed this into a text box when a link is clicked? As mentioned i have a link next to a text box, when clicked i want the javascript to generate this string and insert into the text box.